# VBA PowerPoint: Get all shapes with text

Tags: vba, powerpoint

Can't quite figure out what's going wrong here.
I get a object variable not set for the last debug.print line.
N.B - the debug.print line in the loop prints fine and there are three shaped that should be in the array (and i is at 3 at the end of the loop).
I think I may just not understand exactly how arrays / variable setting works, I'm new to VBA (I do have programming experience though).

```
Dim allShapes As Shapes
Set allShapes = ActivePresentation.Slides(11).Shapes
Dim textShapes() As Shape
ReDim textShapes(0 To 2)
i = 0

For Each thisShape In allShapes
    If thisShape.HasTextFrame Then
        If thisShape.TextFrame.HasText Then
           Debug.Print thisShape.TextFrame.TextRange.Text
           Set textShapes(i) = thisShape
           i = i + 1

           ReDim textShapes(0 To i) As Shape
        End If

     End If
Next thisShape
ReDim textShapes(0 To i - 1)

Debug.Print textShapes(1).TextFrame.TextRange.Text
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`For Each thisShape In allShapes`

What is `allShapes`? Is it declared somewhere?

Also to preserve  the shapes in the array you have to use `Redim Preserve`

Is this what you are trying? This loops thorough all the shapes in Slide 1.

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim textShapes() As Shape, i as Long

    ReDim textShapes(0 To 2)

    i = 0

    For Each thisShape In ActivePresentation.Slides(1).Shapes
        If thisShape.HasTextFrame Then
            If thisShape.TextFrame.HasText Then
               Set textShapes(i) = thisShape
               i = i + 1
               ReDim Preserve textShapes(0 To i) As Shape
            End If
         End If
    Next thisShape

    Debug.Print textShapes(1).TextFrame.TextRange.Text
End Sub
```

Also as the title of the question say `Get all shapes with text`; In such a case you will have to loop through the array. to get all shapes with text.

Comment: yup the preserve did it! Thanks!